# Calculate inertia tensors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, physics

Moments of inertia and inertia tensors are well-known characteristics of rigid bodies in physics and applied mathematics. How to calculate them in Mathematica? Is possible to use regions which was introduced recently in version 10?

Comment: Maybe of interest: I used the inertia tensor to identify symmetries of an object in an image [in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17065/245).

Comment: @Jens An interesting idea!

Comment: I was going to say that I was almost positive that the Wolfram Mathematica 10 product page had a splash-screen where they showed a rendering of a human tooth and overlayed it with the principle axes and labeled it with the eigenvalues of the inertia tensor, and then I saw you answered your question, hehe. +1

Comment: There is also `SolidData["Steinmetz2Solid", "InertiaTensor"]` and friends, although I think it only works for named solids, and not arbitrary regions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Mathematica* **10.4**, `MomentOfInertia` is now built-in. So we can compute inertia tensor for named, arbitrary and formula regions. Some examples:

```
MomentOfInertia[Ball[]]

(* {{(8 Pi)/15, 0, 0}, {0, (8 Pi)/15, 0}, {0, 0, (8 Pi)/15}} *)

reg = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {20, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MomentOfInertia[reg]
(* {{0.0227787, 0.085264, 0.0937136}, {0.085264, 0.0226137, 
  0.0801547}, {0.0937136, 0.0801547, 0.0183785}} *)
```

Answer (score 19):

The inertia tensor is defined as an integral of the following tensor over the body region

```
vars = {x, y, z};
r2 = IdentityMatrix[3] Tr[#] - # &@Outer[Times, vars, vars];
r2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It is very simple to do with integration over a region

```
Integrate[r2, vars ∈ region]
```

It can be wrapped in the following function

```
inertiaTensor[reg_, assum_: {}] := 
  Module[{x, y, z, d = RegionEmbeddingDimension[reg], r2, vars},
   vars = {x, y, z};
   r2 = IdentityMatrix[3] Tr[#] - # &@Outer[Times, vars, vars];
   If[d == 2, r2 = r2 /. z -> 0; vars = {x, y}];
   If[d == 1, r2 = r2 /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}; vars = {z}];
   Integrate[r2, vars ∈ reg, Assumptions -> assum]/
     Integrate[1, vars ∈ reg, Assumptions -> assum] // 
    Simplify];
```

I assume that the body have a unit mass. I also assume that 2D bodies lie in xy plane and 1D bodies lie on the axes z.

Now we can prepare the following demonstration which corresponds to known [list of moments of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia)

```
gr3d = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Thickness[0.03], 
     FaceForm[Opacity[0.5]], Blue, #, Gray, Thickness[0.01], 
     Line[{-#, #} & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]], Black, 
     Text @@@ {{x, {1.1, 0, 0}}, {y, {0, 1.1, 0}}, {z, {0, 0, 1.1}}}},
     ImageSize -> 150, PlotRange -> 1, Boxed -> False, 
    SphericalRegion -> False, ViewAngle -> Pi/10] &;
gr2d = gr3d@{FaceForm[Opacity[1]], Texture[#], EdgeForm[None], 
         Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
          VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
             1}}]} &@Rasterize[#, Background -> None] &@
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5], Blue}], 
      Blue, #}, PlotRange -> 1.01, ImageSize -> 150, 
     Background -> Transparent] &;

Manipulate[
   Row@{type[[1]], 
     MatrixForm[m inertiaTensor @@ type[[2 ;;]]]}, {type, 
    Thread[#[[All, 2 ;;]] -> #[[All, 1]]]}, 
   Initialization :> {type = #[[1, 2 ;;]]}] &@{{"Point", 
   gr3d@Point[{0, 0, 1}], Point[{0, 0, r}], r > 0},
  {"Rod", gr3d@Line[{{0, 0, -1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2}}], 
   Interval[{-a/2, a/2}], a > 0},
  {"Circle", gr2d@Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, r], r > 0},
  {"Disk", gr2d@Disk[], Disk[{0, 0}, r], r > 0},
  {"Cylinder", gr3d@Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2}}, 1/2], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, -h/2}, {0, 0, h/2}}, r], {r > 0, h > 0}},
  {"Tetrahedron", gr3d@Tetrahedron[#], Tetrahedron[s #], s > 0} &@
   PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"],
  {"Sphere", gr3d@Sphere[], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], r > 0},
  {"Ball", gr3d@Ball[], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r], r > 0},
  {"Cone", gr3d@Cone[{{0, 0, 2/3}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1/2], 
   Cone[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, 0}}, r], {r > 0, h > 0}},
  {"Ellipsoid", gr3d@Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.7, 0.5, 0.3}], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}},
  {"Rectangle", gr2d@Rectangle[-{1, 1}/2, {1, 1}/2], 
   Rectangle[-{a, a}/2, {a, a}/2], a > 0},
  {"Cuboid", gr3d@Cuboid[-{0.4, 0.3, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.2}], 
   Cuboid[-{a, b, c}/2, {a, b, c}/2], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Good afternoon! I invite you to think about the problem. I'm in love with her now, but I haven't received a decision yet https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277997/inertia-tensors-for-non-typical-rigid-bodies

Answer (score 2):

For the Cuboid is wrong the right answer is

```
{"Cuboid", gr3d@Cuboid[-{0.4, 0.3, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.2}], 
 Cuboid[-{b, b, b}, {b, b, b}], {b > 0, b > 0, b > 0}}}
```

because the sides are equal

Comment: Please provide more detail.