# Boundary identification

Tags: image-processing

I want to get boundaries of grains from a microphotograph. I have tried using different methods but because of the texture of background I am not able to get smooth boundaries.

[image: Microphotograph]

Codes that I've tried are:

1)

```
EdgeDetect[
  DeleteSmallComponents[
    FillingTransform[
      MorphologicalBinarize[Import["http://imgur.com/o7OF9jG.jpg"], .5]]]]
```

This gives output as:

[image: Result 1]

2)

```
EdgeDetect[
  FillingTransform[
    DeleteSmallComponents[
      ColorNegate[
        ChanVeseBinarize[Import["http://imgur.com/o7OF9jG.jpg"]]], 2000]]]
```

This gives output as:

[image]

However, I am not satisfied with either of the results. Can I use any other way/function to determine a more accurate grain boundaries from this image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach is to smooth the image (here I've used the curvature flow filter, which is a nonlinear edge-preserving smoothing filter) and then binarize before doing the edge detection.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIiTZ.jpg"]  
curve = CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 40];
EdgeDetect[FillingTransform[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[curve]]]]
```

[image]

Dilating makes it look a bit smoother, but you may (or may not) want to do that, depending on what you are doing with the images.

```
Dilation[EdgeDetect[FillingTransform[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[curve]]]], 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

My high-level strategy would be to use `WatershedSegmentation` on a gradient image (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104467/242) for a description of what this function does), starting from a marker image that looks like this:

[image]

So `WatershedSegmentation` can grow the highlighted "seeds" until they touch at the highest gradient border.

So first step: Get the marker image. It doesn't have to follow the grain contours perfectly, so I can use a large blurring filter to smooth out all the high-frequency details:

```
GaussianFilter[img, 100]
```

[image]

The grains are easily recognizable in this image using any segmentation technique you like, I'll just use `Binarize`:

```
binary = Binarize[gaussian];
```

[image]

To get the markers as above, I take the perimeter of that binary image and make it "wider" using `Erosion`:

```
markers = 
  Erosion[ColorNegate[MorphologicalPerimeter[binary]], 
   DiskMatrix[50]];
```

That's it, now we can pass the whole thing to `WatershedSegmentation:`

```
(seg = WatershedComponents[
    ColorConvert[ImageAdd[GradientFilter[img, 5]], "Grayscale"], 
    markers]) // Colorize
```

(You might want to play with the `GradientFilter` filter size to improve the result)

[image]

You can get the perimeter using

```
perimeter = Binarize[ColorNegate[Image[seg]]];
HighlightImage[img, perimeter]
```

[image]

To visualize the result, I'll show it filled:

```
HighlightImage[img, FillingTransform@perimeter]
```

[image]

Comment: Instructive description!